# Using dispose() when using StatefulBuilder in a StatelessWidget

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using a `StatefulBuilder` widget to update my values and it all works fine.

```
StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
   return Mywidget();
});
```

Since this widget is in a Tab view, when I scroll to the next tab, I get the below exception in console.

```
E/flutter ( 7147): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(188)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 7147): setState() called after dispose(): _StatefulBuilderState#09a22(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
E/flutter ( 7147): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback. The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter ( 7147): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
E/flutter ( 7147): #0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1097:9)
E/flutter ( 7147): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1123:6)
E/flutter ( 7147): #2      ImageItem.actionColumn.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:silkthread/widgets/image_item.dart:197:19)
E/flutter ( 7147): #3      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1379:54)
E/flutter ( 7147): #4      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
E/flutter ( 7147): #5      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
E/flutter ( 7147): #6      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
E/flutter ( 7147): #7      Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
E/flutter ( 7147): #8      _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
E/flutter ( 7147): #9      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1379:54)
E/flutter ( 7147): #10     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
E/flutter ( 7147): #11     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
E/flutter ( 7147): #12     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
E/flutter ( 7147): #13     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
E/flutter ( 7147): #14     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
E/flutter ( 7147): #15     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:33:20)
E/flutter ( 7147): #16     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
E/flutter ( 7147): #17     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
```

Since the page which has `StatefulBuilder` widget is a `StatelessWidget`, I can't call `dispose()` method.

So while using `StatefulBuilder` how can I avoid this exception?

Edit:
I am trying something same as mentioned in the article https://medium.com/flutter-community/stateful-widgets-be-gone-stateful-builder-a67f139725a0.

```
class ImageItem extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return StatefulBuilder(
           builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
               setState(() {
                 likesCount = post.likesCount;
               });

              return ActionChip(label: Text(likesCount);
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

create and implement your own StatefulBuilder, add dispose method, like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef Disposer = void Function();

class MyStatefulBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulBuilder({
    Key key,
    @required this.builder,
    @required this.dispose,
  }) : assert(builder != null),
        super(key: key);

  final StatefulWidgetBuilder builder;
  final Disposer dispose;

  @override
  _MyStatefulBuilderState createState() => _MyStatefulBuilderState();
}

class _MyStatefulBuilderState extends State<MyStatefulBuilder> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => widget.builder(context, setState);

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    widget.dispose();
  }
}
```

use it like this:

```
return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Hello, world.'),
        content: MyStatefulBuilder(
          dispose: () {
            print('dispose!!!!!!!!!!!!');
          },
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
            return Container();
          }
    )
);
```

Comment: Brilliant! Seems very strange that the StatefulBuilder built in to Flutter doesn't have this capability.

Comment: @JimGomes Especially since it wouldn't break the existing API to add the dispose function as an optional parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code

```
if(mounted) {
  setState(() { ... });
}
```

to avoid `setState()` being called when the widget is not mounted.

Comment: It says undefined name when used inside builder method of StatefulBuilder.

Comment: Hard to tell. Can you please add more code to your question.

Comment: It should be in your `State` class, the class which extends <State>

Comment: I am not using State class as my page is not a StatefulWidget. It's a stateless widget and I use StatefulBuilder to update my values. Updated my question with more details.

Comment: You can use when u are you using StatefulBuilder. Please refer to the link provided in the edited post.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have added some more code for your understanding. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: What code is this line referring to exactly? E/flutter ( 7147): #2      ImageItem.actionColumn.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:silkthread/widgets/image_item.dart:197:19)

Comment: It refers to setState

Comment: I don't see `setState` being called, only being passed as parameter and the error message does seem to indicate that it's being called.

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to solve this. You could pass a `GlobalKey` to be able to access the state and query the `mounted` property of the `StatefulBuilder`, but I wouldn't consider that a good approach. I'd suggest to use `StatefulBuilder` in a stateful widget and create an issue to have `StatefulBuilder` check `mounted` or pass `state` to the builder for custom code to be able to check itself.

Comment: Thanks for the info. When using Stateful widget, there would be no need to use StatefulBuilder, right? Please correct me ifI am wrong. I will raise an issue on this.

Comment: I haven't used it myself yet, but I think you are right.

Comment: I'd suggest to not use stateful builder at all. This is rarely a good idea. Prefer a StatefulWidget instead

Comment: Yea, I was initially using StatefulWidget and came across the linked post and modified my code. I will revert back.. So StatefulBuilder is not much useful widget.